# fuser command output process ID extraction

Tags: linux, awk, fuser

Try to extract the process ID that is using a given port number from the **fuser** output as below

```
$ fuser 9092/tcp
9092/tcp:             5920
```

Extracting the PID using **awk** is not happening

```
$ fuser 9092/tcp | awk -F: '{print $2}'
9092/tcp:
```

from the extracted PID, I want to do `ls -l /proc/5920/exe` like

```
ls -l /proc/$(fuser 9092/tcp | awk -F: '{print $2}')/exe
```

Versions of the binary as below:

```
bash --version  # GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
fuser --version  # fuser (PSmisc) 22.20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The informal part of the output from `fuser` goes to standard error. The output to standard output is already computer-readable. (This is a feature, not a bug.)

Trivially, you can redirect standard error to get rid of the stderr output if you think it's useless or distracting.

```sh
$ fuser 9092/tcp 2>/dev/null
5920
```

You can easily establish this for yourself by piping e.g. to `nl`

```sh
$ fuser 9092/tcp | nl
9092/tcp: 
1       5920
```

Notice how the `9092/tcp:` output does not get a line number -- it's not being piped to `nl`.

So your actual code could look like

```sh
ls -l /proc/$(fuser 9092/tcp 2>/dev/null)/exe
```

(though usually [don't use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: It works this way for me with the help of your solution 
`ls -l /proc/$(fuser 9092/tcp 2>/dev/null | awk -F'[' '{print $1}' | sed 's/ //g')/exe`   or   
`ls -l /proc/$(fuser 9092/tcp 2>/dev/null | nl | awk '{print $2}')/exe`

Comment: The Awk and `sed` junk is completely unnecessary. The `nl` is just to help you see what's going on, and not part of the solution.